# "default naming conventions" moose perl

Tags: perl, moose

In the moose manual it gives examples on how to change the accessor names e.g.

```
reader => get_myvariable,
writer => set_myvariable,
```

and then it states:

> If you're thinking that doing this over and over would be insanely
>   tedious, you're right! Fortunately, Moose provides a powerful
>   extension system that lets you override the default naming
>   conventions. See Moose::Manual::MooseX for more details.

I was browsing through the MooseX manual but couldn't locate the documentation on this. Is anyone familiar with this and could point me to the right part of the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is referring to the following section of the MooseX page: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/MooseX.pod#MooseX::FollowPBP. (Note that the next section on `MooseX::SemiAffordanceAccessor` has an alternative option.)

Essentially, all you need to do is add `use MooseX::FollowPBP` to your imports.

See the actual module's documentation for more information: https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::FollowPBP